# HttpURLConnection application crashes with ESP8266

Tags: java, android, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a ESP8266 simple http server with following Lua script

```
print("My First Lua program")
--print(adc.readvdd33())
print("Setting Wifi")
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)            --[[ STATION + AP --]]
wifi.setphymode(wifi.PHYMODE_N)         --[[ IEEE 802.n --]]
print(wifi.getmode())
print(wifi.getphymode())
wifi.sta.config("srs", "cometomyn/w0")
tmr.delay(5000000)
print("Delay out")
--print(wifi.sta.getip())
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP) 
srv:listen(80,function(conn) 
    conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload) 
        print(payload) 
        conn:send("<h1> ESP8266<BR>Server is working!</h1>")
        conn:close()
        end) 
end)
```

When i connect to server through my laptop with chrome, i am getting "Server is working!" response.

But when i connect through android app i made, it is crashing :( . Following is my app code

```
public class HttpManager {
public static String downloadUrl(String uri) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    InputStream is=null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(10000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //add request header
        //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        //con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        is = con.getInputStream();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    String contentOfMyInputStream = sb.toString();
    return contentOfMyInputStream;
}
```

}

I am calling this HttpManager in an assync task. With this app i am able to get response from sites like google ! .

I am not sure which code is having issue !!!
Could anyone can help me to solve this issue ?

Appending crash log too

```
07-18 11:51:04.122    3710-3710/srs.thebewboston I/First success﹕ http
07-18 11:51:04.312    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ java.io.EOFException
07-18 11:51:04.322    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
07-18 11:51:04.322    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:544)
07-18 11:51:04.332    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:784)
07-18 11:51:04.332    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
07-18 11:51:04.342    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
07-18 11:51:04.342    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at srs.thebewboston.HttpManager.downloadUrl(HttpManager.java:38)
07-18 11:51:04.342    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at srs.thebewboston.MainActivity$MyATask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:278)
07-18 11:51:04.342    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at srs.thebewboston.MainActivity$MyATask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:264)
07-18 11:51:04.382    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-18 11:51:04.382    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-18 11:51:04.412    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-18 11:51:04.452    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-18 11:51:04.472    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-18 11:51:04.592    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 11:51:04.612    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-18 11:51:04.652    3710-3985/srs.thebewboston E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
            at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:122)
            at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:59)
            at srs.thebewboston.HttpManager.downloadUrl(HttpManager.java:43)
            at srs.thebewboston.MainActivity$MyATask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:278)
            at srs.thebewboston.MainActivity$MyATask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:264)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Adding my server response also

```
GET  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
GET  Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; MI 3W MIUI/V6.5.3.0.KXDMICD)
GET  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; MI 3W Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.93 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

1st response when i tried with chrome from Laptop (Worked)

2nd response when i tried with my app from mobile (Not worked!!)

3rd response when i tried with chrome from same mobile (Worked)

My Assynctask calling section

```
private class MyATask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        TextView testout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testout);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            testout.append("Starting Task" + '\n');
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String httout = null;
            try {
                httout = HttpManager.downloadUrl(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
            return httout;}
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            //testout.append(values[0]+'\n');}
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            testout.append(result + '\n');}
    }
```

Atask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"http://192.168.1.3");            //This one didn't work
Atask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"http://www.google.com"); //This one worked

Thanks

Comment: `downloadUrl(HttpManager.java:38)`. Which code is on that line?

Comment: `catch (IOException e)`. If you have a catch you should not continue with following code but return.

Comment: I am calling HttpManager with the URL i needed to fetch, presently i am giving the IP address of ESP8266 module as below
Atask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"http://192.168.1.3");

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`. You have that exception because you continue after that catch.

Comment: @SREEJITHS can you log what is returned from server and comment of rest of the code. Is it hitting the server. i doubt that

Comment: Please react on comments and answer the questions. Your remark serves nothing.

Comment: Hi Greenapps,           
I am a newbie to this Java/android, my doubt is, it working without a crash when i give "google.com" instead of my esp module ip "192.168.1.3"

Comment: You already told that. Do not repeat that. Better answer my questinos and react on remarks. Please show complete urls used.

Comment: @greenapps     I am not sure about adding as remarks :(, I will look into it.... 
I tried the following Links
"http://192.168.1.3"
"http://www.google.com"

Comment: Those are no links. Please show full code like String url ="google.com";. Now write both down exactly as you used them. So thell the contents/value of uri in `downloadUrl(String uri) `

Comment: @greenapps   I added async url calling section also, hope now it give a clear idea

Comment: `Adding my server response also`. Those are not your server responses. You found that in the logfiles of your server. Anyhow it looks as if the request is received from your android app too.

Comment: You did noty react on my remark: `catch (IOException e). If you have a catch you should not continue with following code but return.`. Why no reaction? Please add following return there: `return "IOException: " + e.getMessage();`. Please report.

Comment: @greenapps    I tried adding e.getMessage(); in IOException... Now i got message as "IOException:null"

Comment: `downloadUrl(String uri) throws IOException {`. Remove the throws IOException. Add a catch block to the try and put it there. Handle all in downloadUrl(). Then you will know the reason.

Comment: Check this line carefully. Because it seems your input stream is null.
`is = con.getInputStream();`

Comment: @SREEJITHS Has the problem been solved? Is there any more feedback you need? If not I suggest you consider to accept the answer so that SO can mark this question as closed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially three issues with this code:

```
srv:listen(80,function(conn) 
    conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload) 
        print(payload) 
        conn:send("<h1> ESP8266<BR>Server is working!</h1>")
        conn:close()
        end)
```

1. `conn:send()` is asynchronous, see [API docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend). This means you can't close the connection immediately after calling `conn:send()` because the data might not have been sent by the time you close the connection.
2. You reuse the `conn` variable in the two callback functions. So, change `function(conn,payload)` to `function(whatever,payload)` and then do `whatever:send` accordingly.
3. What you're sending back is not a valid HTTP response but just some protocol agnostic HTML snippet.

Look at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/dev/README.md#programming-model for a complete and working example.